# The getSource() method in an action listener does not recognize the buttons i'm referring to

Tags: java, actionlistener

all, I'm a newbie to Java and I'm working on the Lab 12 on the Java textbook, Starting out with Java (Ed.5).

After written the code for constructor, I have created a method to build a panel and add some radio buttons to it. I have registered these radio buttons to an Action Listener called RadioButtonListener. Then I wrote an inner class for RadioButtonListener.

Here is the problem, as I used the getSource() method to determine which button is clicked, the compiler does not recognize the button I indicated.

Here is my coding:

```
private void buildBottomPanel()
{
    bottomPanel = new JPanel();

    JRadioButton greenButton = new JRadioButton("Green");

    JRadioButton blueButton = new JRadioButton("Blue");

    JRadioButton cyanButton = new JRadioButton("Cyan");

    ButtonGroup bottomButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    bottomButtonGroup.add(greenButton);
    bottomButtonGroup.add(blueButton);
    bottomButtonGroup.add(cyanButton);

    greenButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    blueButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    cyanButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    bottomPanel.add(greenButton);
    bottomPanel.add(blueButton);
    bottomPanel.add(cyanButton);
}

private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f)
    {
        if (f.getSource() == greenButton)
        {
            messageLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else if (f.getSource() == blueButton)
        {
            messageLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE); 
        }
        else if (f.getSource() == cyanButton)
        {
            messageLabel.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: since you are trying to access local variable `JRadioButton greenButton`

Comment: Looks like buildBottomPanel() initializes method-local variables, while listener compares action source with object fields. You should review your actual code and if it looks exactly like the example, you should change buildBottomPanel() method to initialize object fields (by removing JRadioButton type declaration from greenButton, blueButton and cyanButton variables).

Comment: You are right. I initialized the button variables in buildBottomPanel() method. Do you mean I should declare the button variables outside of the buildBottomPanel() method? I will try to declare the variable on the outer class when I am on my own computer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try to use `getActionCommand()` instead of `getSource()` as Below :-

```
if (f.getActionCommand().equals("green"))
        {
            messageLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        }
```

or you can use anonymous inner classes as below :-

```
 greenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

              messageLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your suggestion. I used the getActionCommand() for another action listener inner class and it works fine. However, for this inner class, the lab instruction requires me to use the getSource() method and I typed in the coding similar to a sample in the textbook. I am now wondering if the getSource() method in an inner class cannot trace the variable that is local to the method outside of the inner class.

Comment: if local variable is declare as final then only you can use that variable in inner class.